# How do I convert Rtf to Text using ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, text, rtf

How do I convert To Text Format from RTF using ASP.Net?

Comment: I took the liberty to change your "command" style post into a question. We love to help, but we don't like to be bossed around.

Answer (score 4):

You have instructions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488002.aspx)

In C#

```
class ConvertFromRTF
{
    static void Main()
    {

        string path = @"test2.rtf";

        //Create the RichTextBox. (Requires a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.)
        System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

        // Get the contents of the RTF file. Note that when it is
        // stored in the string, it is encoded as UTF-16.
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

        // Display the RTF text.
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s);

        // Convert the RTF to plain text.
        rtBox.Rtf = s;
        string plainText = rtBox.Text;

        // Display plain text output in MessageBox because console
        // cannot display Greek letters.
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(plainText);

        // Output plain text to file, encoded as UTF-8.
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"output.txt", plainText);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work in winforms but can cause serious issues in an asp.net application. You can get "Cannot create windows handle" exception

Comment: @Sam should work if you remove the Windows.Forms.MessageBox-lines. I just quited the entire example.