# RichTextBox throws OutOfMemory on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, out-of-memory, richtextbox

I'm using RichTextBox to convert a string in RTF to plain text, using this piece of code:

```
private string ConvertToText(string rtf)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rtf)) return string.Empty;

    if (!rtf.Contains("{\\rtf")) return rtf.Trim();  

    using (var helper = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox())
    {
        helper.Rtf = rtf;
        var plainText = helper.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(plainText)) return string.Empty;

        return "<< Rule in Rich Text Format converted to Plain Text >>\n\n" 
            + plainText 
            + "\n\n<< Rule in Rich Text Format converted to Plain Text >>";
    }
}
```

It works OK on all developers machines, but it does not work when deployed to an Azure Web Site:

```
{
"$id"             :"1",
"Message"         :"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"Out of memory.",
"ExceptionType"   :"System.OutOfMemoryException",
"StackTrace"      :"   
    at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)\r\n   
    at System.Drawing.Font.GetHeight()\r\n   
    at System.Drawing.Font.get_Height()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_FontHeight()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.get_PreferredHeight()\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.AdjustHeight(Boolean returnIfAnchored)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.set_Multiline(Boolean value)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.set_Multiline(Boolean value)\r\n   
    at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox..ctor()\r\n   
    at ... "
}
```

It happens *no matter the size* of the RTF string. I'm already using the "Copy to Local" property of the `System.Windows.Forms` reference. Does anyone have experience in dealing with RTF and Azure? Is there an alternative way to convert RTF to plain text?

Comment: Could you be more specific in azure part, what kind of Azure service are you using? Virtual Machine? Web Role? Web Sites?

Comment: May be wrong, but I suspect you cannot create a Form's control in azure Web because it has no drawing context.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, @Gusman. But that's Microsoft own suggestion of how to convert a RTF to plain text! So, what alternatives could I use with Azure Web Sites?

Comment: @LucasReis To back up Gunsman see: [The Caution Listed Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx)

Comment: Well, found nothing in C# but here is a really simple function in c++ which you can port to convert to plain text: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?201658-RTF-spcification-****&s=

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How do I convert Rtf to Text using ASP.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407689/how-do-i-convert-rtf-to-text-using-asp-net)

Comment: @ECarterYoung, that answer does not work in my case.

Comment: Why not, regardless you need to tailor your code to avoid the Caution I listed 4 comments ago.  Ill see if i can find a link

Comment: I found your issue in googling for the Web Equivalent for an RTF Text Box.  The issue is that no web accessible namespace contains a native RTF textbox.  Looks like you need another control type, say a file upload that accepts rtf fils then upon submittal returns the text.

Comment: You're getting an OutOfMemoryException because your application is running in a non-interactive session, and the desktop heap size is limited or zero.  You will not be able to instantiate objects which rely on creating a device context.  That's at least one reason for the Caution listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an adapted C# version of this [C++ forum link](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?201658-RTF-spcification-) suggested by @Gusman on the comments:

```
public static string ConvertToText(string rtf)
{
    bool slash = false; //indicates if backslash followed by the space
    bool figure_opened = false; //indicates if opening figure brace followed by the space
    bool figure_closed = false; //indicates if closing brace followed by the space
    bool first_space = false; //the else spaces are in plain text and must be included to the result

    if (rtf.Length < 4) return string.Empty;

    int i = 0;
    i = rtf.IndexOf("\\pard");
    if (i < 1) return "";

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = i; j < rtf.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        char ch = rtf[j];
        char nextCh = rtf[j + 1];

        if (ch == '\\' && nextCh == 'p') // appends \n if \pard, except for first
        {
            if (j > i && j < rtf.Length - 4)
            {
                string fiveChars = rtf.Substring(j, 5);
                if (fiveChars.Equals("\\pard"))
                {
                    builder.Append("\n");
                }
            }
        }

        if (ch == '\\' && nextCh == 'u') // to deal correctly with special characters
        {
            string fourChars = rtf.Substring(j + 2, 4);
            string digits = new string(fourChars.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            char specialChar = (char)int.Parse(digits);
            builder.Append(specialChar);
            j += digits.Length + 5;
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '\\' && nextCh == '{') // if the text contains symbol '{'
        {
            slash = false;
            figure_opened = false;
            figure_closed = false;
            first_space = false;
            builder.Append('{');
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        else if (ch == '\\' && nextCh == '}') // if the text contains symbol '}'
        {
            slash = false;
            figure_opened = false;
            figure_closed = false;
            first_space = false;
            builder.Append('}');
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        else if (ch == '\\' && nextCh == '\\') // if the text contains symbol '\'
        {
            slash = false;
            figure_opened = false;
            figure_closed = false;
            first_space = false;
            builder.Append('\\');
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        else if (ch == '\\') // we are looking at the backslash
        {
            first_space = true;
            slash = true;
        }
        else if (ch == '{')
        {
            first_space = true;
            figure_opened = true;
        }
        else if (ch == '}')
        {
            first_space = true;
            figure_closed = true;
        }
        else if (ch == ' ')
        {
            slash = false;
            figure_opened = false;
            figure_closed = false;
        }

        if (!slash && !figure_opened && !figure_closed)
        {
            if (!first_space)
            {
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
            else
            {
                first_space = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

It works! =D