# RichTextBox working in local server but not on Azure Web API Server

Tags: c#, .net, azure, richtextbox

I am using `RichTextBox` to convert RTF text receives from a rest service to Plain Text.

I have used the code as recommended in this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/cc488002(v=vs.120))

Same is working on local machine, IISExpress server, where the text gets converted to Plain text. However, once deployed on Azure App Service(Web API) i get a blank response without any exception.

I have made sure that `System.Windows.Forms.dll` is present in my bin folder when publishing the code on the server.

The code that is responsible to convert text to plain text.

```
try {
 RichTextBox rtBox = new RichTextBox();
 rtBox.Rtf = cm.Message;
 cm.Message = rtBox.Text;
} catch(Exception ex) {
 System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Error when RTF ::" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

This is the RTF text that i am trying to convert:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 EK03Plain-L01;}{\f1\fnil Courier New;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue128;\red0\green0\blue0;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\b\f0\fs20  \cf2   Sample Text 1\parSample Test 2\b0\f1\par\cf1\par}
```

When running this code on my local machine: I get the below expected output:

```
Sample Text 1 \nSample Test 2
```

But on Azure it just return a blank response. i.e ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.dll` contains a lot of UI code that will most probably not work in Azure websites sandbox. For more details of azure web app sandbox, please refer to [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions).

And there is an workaround without using `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277178/richtextbox-throws-outofmemory-on-azure).